# highchart xaxis and random y value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been working on this for hours and couldnt figure it out, I'd appreciate if anyone could help.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                 type: 'datetime' ,
                tickPixelInterval: 150                
        },
            yAxis: {
                max: 400,
                min: 0,  
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 200,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#ccc',
                    }]

            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <=0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: time + 4 * 50
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()}]
        });
    });

});​
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Instead of current time on the xAxis, I like to start from 00:00 and run 5 seconds increments.
2. I would also like to have the Y value to have random numbers,  not sure why it is not working
3. Last, I would like to get value from another element, and draw a horizontal line on the graph accordingly.

Thanks for looking...

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jennylu98/Ruz4A/104/

Answer (score 3):

1 - Keep a running counter of the seconds (`i`) and use `setHours()` to set the hours,minutes,seconds and milliseconds...the only one you'll really care about is seconds though.

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  var x = (new Date((new Date()).setHours(0,0,i,0)).getTime()),
  y = Math.random()*400;
  series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
  i++; 
}, 1000);
```

2 - Multiply your [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) by something (like your max y value).

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1)
>   that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive),
>   which you can then scale to your desired range.

3 - Slightly unclear on what you're looking for, would you mind specifying?

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruz4A/106/)**

Comment: Hey thanks for the rapid reply.

Your solution is wonderful, however why does it start after all the Y value are plotted? I thought it wasn't working for a sec. 

As for #3, let's say I have a value of 300, I like to draw a static horizontal line on the Y Axis (300). The value is different every time.

Comment: There was a `-19` in the `for` loop near the bottom that was waiting for 19 points before plotting across the graph. I changed it to `-2` here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ruz4A/107/. The third request sounds almost like a threshold line, but I'm not sure if Highcharts supports it currently. I suppose you could do some hacky way of adding a new data series across the whole graph from minX to maxX, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: What you are looking for is a plotBand. You can pass in any value you want from some other element.

Comment: @wergeld - That would be more of a static vertical line it seems. I don't know a whole lot about highcharts either though.

Comment: Chase, For some reason when you replace the for loop with -2, the whole chart doesnt work right. Instead of 5 seconds increments, it changes to 1 second or something like that.

Comment: @Jenny, is the threshhold line supposed to be static or is it a moving target? If a moving target you can add a 2nd series.

Comment: It's a static line based on a value

Comment: @Jenny, then plotBand is the way to go for your threshhold.

Comment: @chase I'm still trying to fix the problem of delay plotting. Are you able to help me out? Thx...: )